# how to insert the tag in existing tag based on the div id using extjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, extjs

I need to insert some tag in the existing tags using extjs based on
the div id 'task123' and also display some alert accordingly.

HTML code:

```
<div id="task123"> <div class="msg" id="sample"> 
  <ul class="msg-icons"> editButton </ul> 
  <h3>Task Details</h3>
  <div>Messages</div> 
  <br/>
  <a class="closeMessageBox" style="cursor:pointer;
      float: right; font-size:7pt;">Click here to close</a> </div>
</div>
```

insert the the new tag in to the old tag after the

```
<div>Messages</div>
```

based on the div id task123 here is the extjs code:

```
 var iconDisplay = {}; 
   iconDisplay.html = '<div class="icon-right">' +'</div>'; 
   var icondisp =
   Ext.fly("task123").query('a.closeMessageBox');
                 Ext.core.DomHelper.insertBefore(icondisp[0], iconDisplay);

   Ext.fly("task123").select('div.icon-right').on('click', function() {
       alert("tested icon right...")    
   },_message);
```

The above code not working properly.

Comment: I don't know how to do this using extjs, but with jQuery you can look at [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: @Niklas Ringdahl pls help for this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087958/timefield-combobox-issue-in-grid-using-extjs4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple javascript to insert new element before link

```
var divNode = document.getElementsByClassName("closeMessageBox")[0];

var newNode = document.createElement("input");
newNode.tye = "text";
divNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, divNode.previousSibling);
```

Comment: can you please help me for this below link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087958/timefield-combobox-issue-in-grid-using-extjs4