# Timefield combobox issue in grid using extjs4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs4

1) Create a grid and add a coulmn of type 'timefield' in grid with renderer of format ('h:i A').
2) Add a row and mke a selection in 'timefield' column, say 4:00 AM.
3) Add another adjecent row and select the same data i.e. 4:00 AM in the dropdown. You will not be able to do this action, and you need to select another time and then come back to the initial selection. It looks to be an ExtJS bug. how to solve this issue.

I have code the following in grid

```
this.mcmGridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({            height: 360,            width: 680,             title: 'Shifts',            store: App.mcmAgentShiftStore,          multiSelect: true,          x: 0,           y: 100,             columns: [
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', header: 'Name', width: 120, dataIndex: 'Name',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', header: 'Initials',  width: 45, dataIndex: 'Initials',
                    editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }
                }, 
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', header: 'Employee Id',  width: 75, dataIndex: 'EmployeeId',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', header: 'Phone#',  width: 100, dataIndex: 'MobilePhoneId',
                    editor: {
                        //TCS: 12/3/2013 cell phone table modified
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        editable: true,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        selectionOnTab: true,
                       // lazyRender: true,
                       // forceSelection: true,
                        store: App.mcmAllMobilePhoneStore,
                        displayField: 'MobileIdentifier',
                        valueField: 'MobilePhoneId',
                        value: 'MobilePhoneId',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        queryDelay: 100,                     
                        specialkey: function(f, e) {
                        if(e.getKey() === e.ESC) {
                                    this.hide(); }
                                },
                       listeners: {
                            load: function(store, recs, success) {
                                if(Ext.typeOf(this.getPicker().loadMask) != "boolean") {
                                    console.log("trying to hide the loadmask");
                                    this.getPicker().loadMask.hide();
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    },

>                   renderer: function(value,metaData,record) {
```

> ```
>                   if(value) {
>                       var MobileStore = Ext.getStore( App.mcmAllMobilePhoneStore);
>                       var Record = MobileStore.findRecord('MobilePhoneId', value);
>                       return Record ? Record.get('MobileIdentifier'): record.get('MobileIdentifier');
>                   } else return "";
>               }//TCS: 12/3/2013 cell phone table modified end*/                           },              
>           { xtype: 'datecolumn', header: 'Start Date', width: 84, dataIndex: 'StartAvailability', format: 'Y-m-d', 
>               editor: {
>                   xtype: 'datefield',
>                   allowBlank: false,
>                   format: 'Y-m-d'
>               }
>           },
>           { header: 'Start', width: 65, dataIndex: 'StartAvailabilityTime', format: 'H:i', 
>               editor: {
>                   xtype: 'timefield',
>                     id: starttime,
>                   format: 'H:i',
>                   increment: 15,
>                   allowBlank: false
>               }
>           },
>           { xtype: 'datecolumn', header: 'End Date', width: 84, dataIndex: 'EndAvailability', format: 'Y-m-d', 
>               editor: {
>                   xtype: 'datefield',
>                   allowBlank: false,
>                   format: 'Y-m-d'
>               }
>           },
>           { header: 'End', width: 65, dataIndex: 'EndAvailabilityTime', format: 'H:i',
>               editor: {
>                   xtype: 'timefield',
>                     id: endtime,
>                   format: 'H:i',
>                   increment: 15,
>                   allowBlank: false
>               }
>           }           ],          tbar: [
>           {
>               text: 'Add',
>               tooltip: 'Add Shift',
>               iconCls: 'icon-shift-add',
>               scope: me,
>               handler: function() {
>                   var agent = this.mcmAgentCombobox.getValue();
>                   if(agent) {
>                       addShift.call(this, agent);
>                   } else {
>                       App.mcmShowMessageBox({
>                           title: 'Important', 
>                           message: 'Please select an agent', 
>                           time: 2000
>                       });
>                   }
>               }
>           }, 
>           {
>               itemId: 'removeShift',
>               text: 'Remove',
>               tooltip: 'Remove Selected Shifts',
>               iconCls: 'icon-shift-remove',
>               scope: me,
>               handler: function() {
>                   this.mcmRemoveShifts();
>               },
>               disabled: true
>           },
>           {
>               itemId: 'closeoutShift',
>               text: 'Closeout',
>               tooltip: 'Closeout Selected Shifts',
>               iconCls: 'icon-shift-closeout',
>               scope: me,
>               handler: function() {
>                   var selection = this.mcmGridPanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
>                   if(selection.length && selection.length > 1) {
>                       App.mcmShowMessageBox({
>                           title: 'Important', 
>                           message: 'Please enter a single shift to perform closeout', 
>                           time: 2000
>                       });
>                       return;
>                   }
>                   App.mcmCloseoutShift(selection[0]);
>               },
>               disabled: true
>           },
>           //TCS: 12/3/2013 cell phone table modification
>           {
>               text: 'Add Cell Phone',
>               tooltip: 'Add CellPhone',
>               iconCls: 'icon-cellphone-add',
>               scope: this,
>               handler: function()
>               {
>                   this.hide;
>                   App.mcmShowMobilePhoneWindow();
>               }
>           }, 
>           //TCS: 12/3/2013 cell phone table modification end          ],          plugins: [ this.mcmRowEditing ],            viewConfig: {},             listeners: {
>           scope: me,
>             beforeedit : function(editor, e) {
>                      editor.down('[@id=starttime]').clearValue();
>                      editor.down('[@id=endtime]').clearValue();
> } }
> ```

I reset the values before edit. but it not working.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for that?

Comment: @JanS am working this functionality for office work though the code is large. so i cannot paste it. can you please help me the logic.

Comment: @JanS I tried the solution which was given in the below link. but no use..  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228292-timefield-combobox-in-grid-selection-issue